# How to load plugin files in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using linkedin plugin for my app. It was working fine for cakephp 1.3. I migrated to cakephp 2.x. I understand you need to load plugins like this

```
CakePlugin::load('Linkedin');
```

It worked. But in my plugin folder I have vendor folder. It is loaded using

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Linkedin.oauth', array('file' => 'OAuth' . DS . 'oauth_consumer.php'));
```

But it says cannot find oauth_consumer.

I appreciate any help.

***UPDATED ***
I have added linkedin [plugin](https://github.com/inlet/CakePHP-LinkedIn) to my app. I have loaded my plugin using CakePlugin::load('Linkedin');. Now I get error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ....\Controller\Component\LinkedinComponent.php on line 95
```

On line 95 of Linkedin component this is what is there

```
    $consumer = $this->_createConsumer();
    $result = $this->Consumer->get($key, $secret, $this->apiPath . $path);
```

It says the get method is not found on linkedincomponent. But the get method is in oauth_consumer.php.

I appreciate all your help

Comment: The App::import statement should not have changed. So your code should still be working then. The cache is cleared, right?

Comment: I cleared it still same problem

Comment: "it says cannot find oauth_consumer" pretty vague.. you should at least provide us with a more verbose error message here. preferably including the strack trace and any information you got along with this error.

Comment: hi mark i appreciate your help. I have updated the question. The plugin is available here https://github.com/inlet/CakePHP-LinkedIn.

Comment: are you shure this plugin is for CakePHP 2.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is not 2.x ready.
You will have to upgrade it yourself.

You could have easily figured that out looking at the folders and files.
In 2.x it would be

```
/Linkedin/Controller/Component/LinkedinComponent.php
```

etc (also note the casing which is important in 2.x)

Most likely you can use the above upgrade shells to do that and make the plugin 2.x compatible.

Comment: Make sure to contribute back to the author once you've upgraded!